# android emulator ==> change heapSize?

Tags: android, android-emulator, heap-memory

I am trying to change the heap size of the emulator, to make sure that my app doesn't run out of memory with 16 mb available? How can i change the heap size on the emulator?
I run the emulator through Eclipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating an emulator u can set the properties, and there is a heap size, which u can change.